# JQuery: Prevent images from loading when parsing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm making a `node js` application that parses and downloads images from the web. However when parsing the `htmlString` jQuery tries to load all images with a `src` tag, causing errors. Normally I would remove the `img` elements like I am doing with other elements, but I need to be able to get and store the `img src` tag from specific img elements for use later. If possible I am trying to replace all the img element's `src` tags into `data-img` tags so that way I can access the stored `url` without having to load every image.

```
    request('example.com', (error, response, htmlString) => { 
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var html = $(htmlString.replace(/(<(\b(style|script|head|link)\b)(([^>]*\/>)|([^\7]*(<\/\2[^>]*>)))|(<\bimg\b)[^>]*>|(\b(background|style)\b=\s*"[^"]*"))/g,"").functionThatReplacesAllImgSrcTagsWithDataImg());
            // How do I replace all src in the img tag with data-img?
            var useLater = [];
            html.find('img.specific__img').each(function(i) {
                useLater.push($(this).attr('data-img'));
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a regular expression, it would probably be a lot more elegant to use `DOMParser` to fix the HTML string - just iterate over elements that match the `img[src]` selector, set their `data-img`, and remove their `src`:

```js
const useLater = [];
const htmlStr = `
<div><img src="foo"></div>
<div><img src="baz"><img src="baz"></div>
`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');
doc.querySelectorAll('img[src]').forEach((img) => {
  const src = img.getAttribute('src');
  img.setAttribute('data-img', src);
  img.removeAttribute('src');
  useLater.push(src);
});
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. How would I also go about removing the other previously mentioned elements completely with DOMParser? i.e., head, script, etc.

Comment: Select them like you would select any element and `remove()` then. `document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => script.remove())`

Comment: One last question, how would I go about replacing all `noscript` elements with something like `<div class="noscript"></div>` so I can access img elements inside noscript from the dom?

Comment: Once the `<noscript>` element is selected, select its parent and use [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) to replace it with your new div.

Comment: I am having a little trouble getting this to work. If I create a text node, it is not html safe and inner elements look like this: `<div class="noscript">&lt;img src="..."&gt;</div>` , but if I use cloneNode I am stuck with the noscript node. `doc.querySelectorAll('noscript').forEach((noscript) => {
            var replacementNode = doc.createElement('div');
            replacementNode.setAttribute('class', 'noscript');
            replacementNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(noscript.innerHTML));
            noscript.parentNode.replaceChild(replacementNode, noscript);
        });`

Comment: Assign to the `replacementNode`'s `innerHTML` if you want to preserve the HTML that existed in the original `noscript` element. (Don't create/append a *text* node)